# Function in WordPress Plugin Not Looking in Path for Imagick

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, imagick

I have inherited a site with a custom plugin that is supposed to decrypt member information and a captured signature and put it into a PDF. The function uses (in this order) TCPDF to create the document; jSignature to convert the decrypted signature to Base30->Base64->Native->SVG; and Imagick to convert the signature to a JPG.

Everything works up to calling the Imagick class to handle the signature file. Imagick is in usr/bin/convert, but the function does not see the class 'Imagick'. Maybe it's not looking? Looking in the wrong place? How do I get the function to look in the right place?

**EDIT**

I have just realized that the site that uses this plugin is in a subdomain, but ImageMagic (and, I believe the Imagick libraries) are installed in the root. Could this be my problem? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: `Imagick` is a [PECL extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) that will need to be installed on system. Can you confirm that the module is loaded by running `php -m`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the subdomain could not see the install in the root. The fastest way to fix it was just install in the subdomain. All is working now. Thanks, everyone, for putting some brain power to this.